# Javascript: Why does declaring a property in a subclass overwrite the same property in a super class as null

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

My question has to do with understanding how classes assign values to properties and how objects are instantiated in Javascript. I would like to understand more how this process works.

If I create two classes where the second inherits from the first

```
class A {
    name

    constructor(name){
        this.name = name
    }
}

class B extends A {
    name
    status

    constructor(name, status){
        super(name)
        this.status = status
    }
}
```

And then create an instance of class B, when I print it to the console

```
x = new B('myClass', true)
console.log(x)
```

It prints that the name variable is undefined

```
B { name: undefined, status: true }
```

I'm pretty sure that the name property in B is over-writing the name property in A, but why doesn't the A constructor assign the new name variable to be the value passed into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct behaviour for the moment (October 2020).

When you set

```
class A {
    name
}
```

This declares a *class field*. It's not a standard yet, it's [a proposal in stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). It's likely to change but not by much. Stage 3 is the candidate stage and might include finishing refinements.

At any rate, what you are seeing is correct according to the current spec of the proposal. Any class fields without initialisers are set to `undefined`. This happens because you have another class field called `name` in `B` without an initialiser. The assignment that happens in the parent constructor will be overwritten.

[Here is the relevant part of the proposal that discusses this behaviour](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/b0784d98fdab4d83b8b6e4558702cd7b8598976b/README.md#fields-without-initializers-are-set-to-undefined):

> #### Fields without initializers are set to `undefined`
>
> Both public and private field declarations create a field in the instance, whether or not there's an initializer present. If there's no initializer, the field is set to `undefined`. This differs a bit from certain transpiler implementations, which would just entirely ignore a field declaration which has no initializer.
>
> For example, in the following example, `new D` would result in an object whose `y` property is `undefined`, not `1`.
>
> ```js
> class C {
>   y = 1; 
> } 
> class D extends C {
>   y; 
> }
> ```
>
> The semantics of setting fields without initializers to `undefined` as opposed to erasing them is that field declarations give a reliable basis to ensure that properties are present on objects that are created. This helps programmers keep objects in the same general state, which can make it easy to reason about and, sometimes, more optimizable in implementations.

Comment: I call `A`'s constructor within `B`'s constructor. Is this field of `name` created and initialized to `undefined` after the constructor finishes executing? Because otherwise I would expect `name` to be initialized to `undefined` but then the constructor of `A` would run and overwrite this value

Comment: @Sam yes, apparently the decision was made to ensure class fields without initialisers to always be `undefined. So, calling `super()` in `B` would initialise `this.name` in `A` but once `B` then the property is wiped back to `undefined`. It seems that declaring a class field without an initialiser implicitly behaves as if you have a `name = undefined` after a `super()` call. I'm not sure I agree with this decision but there is some logic in insulating changes that might affect the objects. If `A` didn't have `name` but later was changed to initialised it, it might change the behaviour of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

This example is borrowed from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends) in order to indicate that this behavior should not happen.

```js
class Animal { 
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} makes a noise.`);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name); // call the super class constructor and pass in the name parameter
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} barks.`);
  }
}

let d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak(); // Mitzie barks.
```

If you check the `Use BabelJS / ES2015` checkbox in the snippet configuration in SO no problem occurs for your code.

```js
class A {
    name;
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    name;
    status;

    constructor(name, status){
        super(name);
        this.status = status;
    }
}

let a = new B('myClass',true);
console.log(a);
```

But if you uncheck it...

```js
 class A {
        name;
        constructor(name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        name;
        status;

        constructor(name, status){
            super(name);
            this.status = status;
        }
    }

    let a = new B('myClass',true);
    console.log(a);
```

...the same code provides the error you noticed.

So what is actually the problem and how to solve this? There is no need to set `name` again in the child class. If you don't, here is the result:

```js
 class A {
        name;
        constructor(name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        status;

        constructor(name, status){
            super(name);
            this.status = status;
        }
    }

    let a = new B('myClass',true);
    console.log(a);
```

Comment: Yeah I had no intention of declaring name twice, but it was a bug I had. Your saying that with BabelJS / es2015 that this isn't a problem? Does that mean that I'm not  using them? I'm using a lot of es6 features like `=>` and `import`. I'm pretty sure I'm using Babel also. I'm Running a react application and using webpack.

Comment: @Sam i can't be aware or answer on an environment problem, but your code runs fine when the certain checkbox is checked. So yes it might that babel might not be loading, but this is totally unsure from y end to judge. In any case you could simply skip the second declaration of `name` . That is also the reason f the MDN example. There is a point in re-declaring a variable in child class when you override a default value given. E.g. `name='John'` in parent could be `name='Peter'` in child class.