# JavaScript class inheritance with default values and coping with many properties

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, constructor

As described in this excellent [article](https://javascript.info/class-inheritance) one can inherit/subclass/extend a JS class like this for example:

```js
class Column {
  constructor(name, align = 'right') {
    this.name = name;
    this.align = align
  }
}

numberFormat = "I'm defined somewhere else"
class FloatColumn extends Column {
  constructor(name, align, format = numberFormat) {
    super(name, align);
    //super(name); Here the instance get's constructed with default value for align as defined in Column
    this.format = format
  }
}
console.log(new Column('col1'))
console.log(new FloatColumn('col2', 'left'))
```

Let's assume subsequent code is parsing `Column` (and related) instances to something else which creates table columns (my usecase is to simplify [webix datatable columns](https://docs.webix.com/api__ui.datatable_columns_config.html) definitions and make them consistent). As this code has already an abundance of properties (with default values) defined, I do not need to define them all in `Column`.
To set default values for certain properties while allowing parsing of any other `kwargs` I could do the following:

```js
class Column {
  constructor({prop1=1, prop2 = 2, prop3 = 3, prop4 = 4, prop5=5, prop6=6, ...kwargs}) {
    Object.assign(this, {prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5, prop6, ...kwargs})
  }
}

numberFormat = "I'm defined somewhere else"
class FloatColumn extends Column {
  constructor({format = numberFormat, ...kwargs}) {
    super({format, ...kwargs});
    this.format = format
  }
}
console.log(new Column({prop1:100, align:'right', height:25, width:100}))
console.log(new FloatColumn({format:'CustomFormat'}))
```

Is there a better way than the above approach? Ideally I would like to define default property values in the following fashion but this might be just a hangover from other languages and not doable in JS.

```js
class Column {
  prop1 = 1 
  prop2 = 2
  prop3 = 3
  prop4 = 4
  prop5 = 5
  prop6 = 6
  constructor(kwargs) {
    Object.assign(this, kwargs)
  }
}

numberFormat = "I'm defined somewhere else"
class FloatColumn extends Column {
  format = numberFormat
  prop5 = 999
  constructor({ format, ...kwargs}) {
    super({format, ...kwargs});
    this.format = format
  }
}
console.log(new Column({prop1:100, align:'right', height:25, width:100}))
console.log(new FloatColumn({format:'CustomFormat', prop5:111}))
```

<s>This approach isn't working, prop1 to prop6 are undefined.</s> 
**UPDATE:** Adjusted this snippet, thanks to @VLAZ comment
Due to the order of the field initialization field `prop5` is always set to 999 now and can't be set when creating a new instance of `FloatColumn`.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: In your last snippet, you don't need to destructure each individual properties in the `Column` constructor, just do `constructor(kwargs) { Object.assign(this, kwargs) }` and you won't extract out undefined things.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ I've amended the snippet and added a follow up question: This approach causes `prop5` to be always set to 999 and not the explicitly parsed value in the instance initialization.

Comment: Ah...sorry, missed that. That's...a thing. You have to be wary of property initialisers because [you *always* get the one in the sub-class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64358462/)