# babel use _defineProperty with class properties

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I use babel with `preset-env`, when I use a class with properties it transform it with `_defineProperty`

example:

```js
class A {
    foo = "bar"
}
```

is transformed to:

```js
function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) {
  key = _toPropertyKey(key);
  if (key in obj) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
      value: value,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
    });
  } else {
    obj[key] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}
function _toPropertyKey(arg) {
  var key = _toPrimitive(arg, "string");
  return typeof key === "symbol" ? key : String(key);
}
function _toPrimitive(input, hint) {
  if (typeof input !== "object" || input === null) return input;
  var prim = input[Symbol.toPrimitive];
  if (prim !== undefined) {
    var res = prim.call(input, hint || "default");
    if (typeof res !== "object") return res;
    throw new TypeError("@@toPrimitive must return a primitive value.");
  }
  return (hint === "string" ? String : Number)(input);
}
class A {
  constructor() {
    _defineProperty(this, "foo", "bar");
  }
}
```

this transformation seems to be caused by [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babel.dev/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) but I do not understand what this transformation provides nor to which new feature of ECMAScript it corresponds.

Comment: The feature is called "class fields", the proposal is linked from the very plugin you already found

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why the transformation is necessary?

Comment: Yes, why it not simply transform to `this.foo = 'bar'` in constructor?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64357900/1048572 for the difference

Answer (score 0):

because babel really doesn't know if something stupid will make the `key` `writable=false` attribute not so to be safe they reset all attribute behavior