# JavaScript subclass method called by parent constructor transiently setting instance properties

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to do some parent/child style inheritence in JavaScript and running into some unexpected behavior:

```js
class Dad {

  constructor() {

    this.init();

  }

  init() {}

}

class Son extends Dad {

  foo;

  init() {

    this.foo = 'bar';

    console.log('init', this.foo);

  }

}

let son = new Son();

console.log('son', son.foo);
```

Expected output:

```
init bar
son bar
```

Actual output:

```
init bar
son undefined
```

Why is son.bar getting unset between `son.init()` being called and the parent constructor returning the new object?

Comment: I see `son bar` when I run this.

Comment: Confirmed... I can't figure out why this is happening in my actual code. Guess I'll close for now and re-open when I can replicate.

Comment: Updated. Adding `foo;` to the `Son` class definition breaks it.

Comment: Why are you using an `init` method? Put `this.foo = 'bar'` in the `constructor` of  `Son` and it'll work

Comment: The parent is defining function calls in the constructor that need to be implemented by the children. That way each time I add a new child type I know I need to implement the functions called by the parent.

Comment: Well [don't call overridden methods from the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821096/1048572)

Comment: I thought that might be the case... hence my not-so-elegant `callMeAfterSuper()` solution below.

Comment: That still doesn't work for a grandson. You'll need a `callMeAfterNew` method.

Comment: I see... is there an established code pattern that solves this?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is an order-of-operations issue.

Execution order:

1. `Son` implied constructor is called
2. ... which calls `super()` or `Dad constructor`
3. `Son.init()` is called
4. `this.foo` is set to `'bar'` (`Dad` constructor finished)
5. After `super()` constructor is finished, the child `Son` class apparently sets properties defined in the `Son` class scope to their defaults, in this case `foo;` or `foo = undefined;`

I don't like it, but one solution is to remove `foo;` from the `Son` class definition. Apparently VS Code intellisense will still pick up on the `foo` property even if it's not defined in the class definition or constructor, which is one of the goals. As far as readability goes, it's slightly worse not to have `foo` in the class definition or constructor.

Another solution:

```js
class Dad {

  // To be called after super() in child constructors
  //    Class field initializers overwrite assignments made by super(), so
  //    anything set here could be overwritten if it were in the constructor
  callMeAfterSuper() {

    this.init();

  }

  init() {}

}

class Son extends Dad {

  foo;

  constructor() {

    super();
    super.callMeAfterSuper();

  }

  init() {

    this.foo = 'bar';

    console.log('init', this.foo);

  }

}

let son = new Son();

console.log('son', son.foo);
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64357900/javascript-why-does-declaring-a-property-in-a-subclass-overwrite-the-same-prope

Answer (score 0):

Addressing [JavaScript subclass method called by parent constructor transiently setting instance properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930532/javascript-subclass-method-called-by-parent-constructor-transiently-setting-inst?noredirect=1#comment130540121_73930532):

Another approach compatible with grandchildren but even less elegant:

```js
    class Dad {

        // To be called after super() in child constructors
        //    Class field initializers overwrite assignments made by super(), so
        //    anything set here could be overwritten if it were in the constructor
        callMeAfterSuper() {

            this.init();

        }

        init() { }

    }

    class Son extends Dad {

        foo;

        constructor() {

            super();
            if( this.constructor.name === Son.name ) super.callMeAfterSuper();

        }

        init() {

            super.init();

            this.foo = 'bar';

        }

    }

    class Grandson extends Son {

        littleFoo;

        constructor() {

            super();
            if( this.constructor.name === Grandson.name ) super.callMeAfterSuper();

        }

        init() {

            super.init();

            this.littleFoo = 'littleBar';

        }

    }

    let son = new Grandson();

    console.log('son', son.foo, son.littleFoo);
```