# assigning class members by object with in child class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can somebody explain to me, why **prop3** of the instance **b** is undefined?

Is there a way, to assign the property from the super class, or do i have to assign it extra from with in my child class?

```
class A {
  prop1?:any;
  prop2?:any;

  constructor(o:any) {
    Object.assign(this, o)
  }
}

class B extends A {
  prop3?:any;
  constructor(o:any){
    super(o);
  }
}

let b= new B({prop1:'1',prop2:'2',prop3:'3',prop4:'4'});

console.log(b);
```

Comment: "*why prop3 of the instance b is undefined*" but...it isn't: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0AOAnA9hgjAPwBcYAdgJ4Dcq62eATCedardMDmRAC5YCuwHjiwAKHKUoBKRO3QB5AEYArAKZCAdJAgBLAOZlRPABY6IAGmg4p7AL6p7KVKG3QAQtFUAPHqrIATGHhkNExcDABmZkoaUM5uPkFhMQkWKRD0dAh+DFUUqVj0R0dUEFUeaEUAXmgyVQB3d1EEegJiAHJ8dvNWhg6GbtaIjojB8IAWDvH22wK2FHiIHDKNEBw9UUU5lCA)

Comment: but only if prop3 is not defined: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0AOAnA9hgjAFxgB2AngLwBEAJgKYBmYAriAC5UDcq62eATAH5i5bih7RgOEhDZZmwNjiwAKHCLIBKRBPQB5AEYArOooB0kCAEsA5iRVsAFlYgAaaDk0SAvql-iUUEtoACFoOgAPNjoSGhh4ZDRMXAwAZg0KAHJ6JlY2TLF0KRk5BSVVdVItRPR0CGYMOgrNQuh-f1QQOjZoAwpoEjoAd1CVBD4CQkz8TNcJ-in+WYn0zNTllIAWKc3M7xbUVGKIHC6zEBwbFQMDlCA

Comment: Honestly, that's [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The practice of using `Object.assign(this, o)` in the constructor should be considered an anti-pattern. There are so many thing that can go wrong. And just because you want to save a few lines of code. I'll really need to look around if there is a good explanation of why it's bad and write one myself if it isn't because it's *very* common and *so very wrong*. There is further complications with the class field semantics in JS. Which apparently TS side-steps to introduce 1/2

Comment: *slightly different* semantics. The issue you see *right now* is just related to how TS compiles the code `prop3:any='default';` as a class field gets compiled as `this.prop3 = 'default';` in the constructor. See the code to the right in the playground. This case aligns with plain JS class field semantics - the declaration in the current class takes precedence. However, when you have a declared but uninitialised field, the correct result is `undefined` value for it. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64358462). This is where TS mismatches JS.  2/2