# Javascript extend parent don't update field

Tags: javascript

I have a simple example of a Javascript class with a single method `_init`
The second class `ClassA` extends class `Parent`

If i try to update an property of the `ClassA` inside `_init` method, it doesn't work.

This is a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gwsq615e/

In my exmaple, `_varTest` is still `undefined`, but i already change the value in the `_init` method from `ClassA`.

I don't understand why the value of `_varTest` is not `test`, but `undefined`, because `_init` method is already called in the constructor of class `Parent`.

**Update**:

I updated my JS Field https://jsfiddle.net/z2rawey7/
I read the [Javascript: Why does declaring a property in a subclass overwrite the same property in a super class as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64357900/javascript-why-does-declaring-a-property-in-a-subclass-overwrite-the-same-prope) and again, very disapoting.

However, i am very disappointing on how JS classes work. In my example, ClassB works very well just because i call the `_init` method in ClassB constructor. But `_init` method also call parent `_init` method.

This is not really the desired behavior.

Is there another way I can extend the functionality of a method or is this the JS world and I have to give up?

In PHP this works. Is there a way to make a js proposal change? This js functionality doesn't make any sense.